# Meteor tomi:upload Add imageversion property on client side

Tags: meteor

is there any way to add imageproperty on client side? i pass my folder path from callback using following way

```
{{> upload_bootstrap fileTypes='image/*' formData=myFormData }}
```

somehow i want to pass
  `imageVersions: {myPhotos: {width: 100, height: 100}}` using client side.

i have already define `imageVersions: {photos: {width: 1024, height: 1024}}` in  `UploadServer.init({});`

Thanks,